# Can the 'standard' set of bullets for SE sites be added to the help/on-topic page of this site?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, help

I recently asked a question, and wasn't completely sure whether it was on-topic.

The reason for this is because the [on-topic page for this site](https://ux.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) doesn't have those bullet points at the top saying what is on topic:

> **What topics can I ask about here?**
>
> User Experience Stack Exchange is for User Experience Designers, Information Architects, and Human Computer Interaction researchers.

Most SE sites have (just after that) something along the lines of `If you have a question about ...`... and then a list of bullet points. (see [AskDifferent](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), [Super User](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic), [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).)

Has this been missed out on purpose for this site? If so, why? If not, can it be added? (not that many people actually read the help center... :P)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We're a bit deliberately vague about that, really it's easier to say what's off topic (graphic design, code implementation) than on topic. The blurb deliberately focuses on who's asking the question rather than what specifically it's about.

I'm not personally sure that section can really be expanded without presenting an overly narrow view of what UX covers but I'd be glad to hear suggestions.

For reference the similar section in our "tour" lists the following things as "ask about", they're also deliberately vague:

- Specific UX design problems
- UX issues that can be solved with expert advice or existing research
- Questions about HCI and user research
- Real problems or questions that you’ve encountered

I guess we could toss these into the help center page as well if that would be useful.

Comment: honestly, these are good enough! It will give *some* starter - but I probably should have checked the tour page when I posted!

Comment: Good bulletpoints, although the last one is a bit of an invite for people to ask things like the "*isn't it annoying that cardoors only open outwards? What's the deal with that?*" type posts that we all 'love'.

Comment: @JonW I think that last one is generic boilerplate the sites all start with, we just didn't remove it, either.

Comment: Threw those in for now, thoughts?